# Plugin: Translated plugin is "not translated"

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, translation

I created a "site specific plugin" what adds a custom post type to my wordpress instance. I made a `.po` file for it with `PoEdit` and even `Loco Translate` shows that it's 100% translated, but it's not working.

Structure:

```
- plugins
 - mysitecore.php
 - mysitecore
  |
  - languages
   |
   - mysitecore-hu_HU.po
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: Can you post some code? An example of output that should be translated but isn't, and the bit where you load your textdomain?

Comment: the `.po` is the file that is "human editable". the file needed by WordPress is the `.mo`.

Comment: Read this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/289622/translated-strings-not-appearing-what-am-i-missing

Comment: @mmm I uploaded the `.mo`, too, still not working

Comment: @bueltge tried this, but not working